# Is there still cheap accommodation (less than 600 ฿ per person per night) on Ko Phi Phi?

Tags: budget, accommodation, thailand, phi-phi

I know Ko Phi Phi is probably the most expensive island in Thailand but despite the crowds it is still a beauty and worth visiting in my opinion. Last time there I didn't plan anything and ended up paying a walk-in rate of 900 Baht for a room I didn't like very much.

Can one still find a room/beach hut (with fan of course) for less than 600 Baht (preferably cheaper)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update Jan 2017**

The prices have gone up, but it is still possible to find deals around the 500-600 Baht mark, especially in dorms. Booking search engines still give a good indication of which places to contact. Direct contact is still a great way to bring the price down.

---

On the low season no problem at all. Last May I heard several people mentioning the region of 200-300 baht per night for the best superior rooms. How to go about getting those special deals are a bit more hit and miss. I've heard that it might work to call to any hostel or guesthouse found online and negotiating a price, they might be willing to slice the web-price because it is the low season.

In low seasons you can also play them against each other and possibly carve a little bit off the price too.

In the high season (December-March) you can still find accommodation in dorms easy for 300 baht. As of writing this message I see there is a place called "Phutawan Bamboo Resort" that has double bed rooms for 250 baht even in december.

So I would say yes, there are still deals to be made. And of course you get what you pay for in many cases, and on Phi Phi I would try and find pictures of the place, or if I'm there I would ask to see the room first.